# Function to convert to csv form and convert it to 2-dimensional list form in python

Tags: python, arraylist

I wanna make

Input:

```
x: 1,2,3
y: 4,5,6
```

Output:

```
xy: [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

using function `parse_list(str_x, str_y)`

I'm a beginner of programming... Please help me.

```
def parse_list(str_x, str_y):
    list_x = str_x.split(',')
    list_y = str_y.split(',')
    xy=[]
    for i in range(len(list_x)):
        xy[i][0]=list_x[i]
        xy[i][1]=list_y[i]
    str_x = input('x: ')
    str_y = input('y: ')
    parse_list(str_x, str_y)
```

It doesn't work, please tell me the better way.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error? You should add more information to your question.

Comment: I think you're looking for `zip(str_x,str_y)`

Comment: are `x` and `y` two rows in a `CSV`? are they 3 columns or one string column

Comment: Format & grammar improvement, moderate the tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting an `IndexError`, because the list is empty when you are trying to access its element with `xy[i][0]=list_x[i]`. You should add elements to the list (for example using `.append()`) before accessing them.

---

If you want to keep the resulting list with string elements, then this should work:

```
def parse_list(str_x, str_y):
    return list(
        zip(str_x.split(','), str_y.split(',')))
```

If you want to convert all the elements to `int`, then you could try this instead:

```
def parse_list(str_x, str_y):
    xy = []
    for x, y in zip(str_x.split(','), str_y.split(',')):
        # careful: this may raise 'ValueError' if its not a valid 'int'
        xy.append([int(x), int(y)])

    return xy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings with commas, map the items to integers, and `zip` the two lists:

```
def parse_list(str_x, str_y):
    return list(zip(map(int, str_x.split(',')), map(int, str_y.split(','))))
```

This returns a list of tuples. If you prefer that it returns a list of lists you can map the tuples that `zip` generates to lists:

```
def parse_list(str_x, str_y):
    return list(map(list, zip(map(int, str_x.split(',')), map(int, str_y.split(',')))))
```